# position:absolute in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm trying to put together a simple 2-column page with text on the left, and various logos and things on the right. At the very bottom of the right column, I need to place some text. A simple `position: absolute; width: 250px; bottom: 0;` seemed like all I needed. Here's the code I came up with, also hosted [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42948076/test.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #eee;
}#content{
    background: white;
    width: 900px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}#text{
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}.left{
    width: 634px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
}.right{
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}.bottom{
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    bottom: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="body">
                <table border=0>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td id="text" class="left">
                            Some text
                        </td><td class="right">
                            <center class="bottom">
                                Bottom
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

That very solution works in all browsers except Firefox. Firefox treats the element almost like it's set to `position:fixed`, locking it to the bottom of the screen, rather than the bottom of the element (which is typically off the bottom of the screen). I can't seem to find anyone else having this problem, which implies I'm doing something wrong. I've messed with this for hours, but the results have been unchanging. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly - firefox is pretty much in sync with the specifications. You can see details about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position)

Now to answer the question of "why" (others have responded to the how :). As per my understanding the specification doesn't state (re)computing the position on page scroll. That's pretty much implementation dependent IMO. If no relatively positioned parent exists for an absolutely positioned element, it's positioned with respect to the displayable viewport/window. So if you open Firebug, you'll find the element is `bottom:0` from top of the firebug window. If you scroll it's value doesn't seem to be recomputed.

Things do get funny when you start positioning with respect to the window and you should know the repercussions (you probably stumbled on one of them :) It's better to wrap it in a parent div like @Rohit suggested or using floats like @thenewguy mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Use two `div`s for positioning. Like this

**[live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/A4t1wgic)**

**Code is**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #eee;
}#content{
    background: white;
    width: 900px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}#text{
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}.left{
    width: 634px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
}.right{
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
    position: relative;
}.bottom{
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    bottom: 0;
  background:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="body">
                <table border=0>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td id="text" class="left">
                            Some text
                        </td><td>
<div class="right">
                      <center class="bottom">
                                Bottom
                            </center>
                      </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All you did is give `#right` and `.bottom` fixed heights. `#right` needs to be the same height as `.left`, which will be taller.

Answer (score 0):

You are making this more difficult than it needs to be. This answer is based upon your description, but I believe it should work for you. Also, I am going to do this based off of percentages for the internals because I don't believe in using pixels (dealing with mobile devices has steered me away from that). Here it goes:

```
body {
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #eee;
}
#content {
background: white;
width: 900px;
text-align: left;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#left{
width: 72%;
border-right: 2px solid black;
overflow: hidden;
}
#right{
width: 25%;
text-align: center;
float: right;
overflow: hidden;
}
#bottom{
float: right;
width: 25%;
}
```

You should put that above code into a stylesheet file and call it instead of just placing the code onto the webpage, but that is just semantics. Here is the HTML code for this stylesheet:

```
<html>
    <head>
    ... (do whatever you need to here, including the stylesheet call)
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="left">
            ...(place your stuff that goes on the left here)
            </div>
            <div id="right">
            ...(place your stuff that goes on the right here)
            </div>
            <div id="bottom">
            ...(place your stuff that goes on the bottom right here)
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

That should give you the basic layout. Now, remember that if the left side div is not the same height as the right side divs, then your vertical line that you are creating between the two sections will not go all the way down. Let me know how this works and I will see what I can do to help you further.

**Just for future reference, I tend to stay away from using tables for styling. They tend to get difficult to deal with once you get a webpage to be fairly complex. Divs and other elements tend to work much better.

Comment: I use an external stylesheet in the actual site, I just combined it here to display in a single file. Also, believe me, I know all about the horrors of tables. I did that page with a table because I was  having trouble getting older versions of IE to display `float`ed elements correctly. I'll try your code for doing it without a table though, maybe I'll get lucky. I would love to do this page without a table.

Comment: Using your code, anything that's `float:right` has its top edge right at the bottom edge of `#left`. If I move the HTML for `#right` before `#left`, that part works, but `#bottom` still hangs off the bottom of `#content`.